# How to link multiple LLVM IRs into one .so file?

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, llvm-ir

I have three files as follows:

```
    Counter.cpp
    Counter.h
    native-lib.cpp
```

These three files are jni code.

I want to convert the cpp file into an LLVM IR file first, and then make some modifications on the LLVM IR file.

Finally, the modified IR file is generated into a .so file.

What LLVM command can do the above mentioned?

Comment: you want to get the object file out of the binary file ( .so ), or you want to the textual IR? in different words, what kind of modifications you want to make?

Comment: I want to make changes on IR